# Keep original __TypeId__ header in DLT, retry topic

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, typeid

everyone
I use spring boot: 3.2.1, kafka: 3.1.1

1. I send message to kafka topic topic-main with header: **TypeId** = "SomeClass"
2. Service rises some error
3. After max-retries count works DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer which sends message to retry-topic: topic-retry

   public TopicPartition getTopicPartitionByRetryPolicy(String
   retryTopic, String dltTopic, ConsumerRecord consumerRecord) {

   ```
       var retries = consumerRecord.headers().lastHeader("retries");
       if (retries == null) {
         retries = new RecordHeader("retries", new byte[] {1});
         consumerRecord.headers().add(retries);
       } else {
         retries.value()[0]++;
       }
       if (retries.value()[0] > backOffProperties.getRetryCount()) {
         log.error("Publishing to DLT topic");
         return new TopicPartition(dltTopic, consumerRecord.partition());
       } else {
         log.error("Publishing to RETRY topic");
         return new TopicPartition(retryTopic, consumerRecord.partition());
       }   }
   ```

In retry topic I receive event with header: **TypeId** = "java.lang.String"

During debugging I see this header in array bytes into consumerRecord, however after produce event header value becomes "java.lang.String"

How should I fix this behaviour ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure I understand what the issue is. It would be better if you could come up with a small sample app and instruct what needs to be done to reproduce the issue exactly.